# Move a vm from Vmware Workstation 10 towards ESX

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, vmware-workstation

I need to move a vm from VMware Workstation 10 towards ESX connected remotely within VMware Workstation 10. The issue is that when I try to drag and drop the Windows Server 2012 R2 from one place to another I get the error message you can see below (Upload Failed: Failed to open disk: Windows Server 2012 R2.vmdk). I thought it was an issue about permission, but I guess it si not, the vm is shutted down.
I read the following article which it explain how to operate, but it didn't help:
https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-8C854257-8595-4877-B985-1DC801E98E88.html
I forgot to say that the host machine is a Windows Server 2003 SP2.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX2SU.jpg)

Thank you in advance

Comment: What version is the ESXi server you are trying to upload the VM to? And what's the Hardware version of your VM?

Comment: ESXi is 5.5 version, my mistake, sorry everyone, the Vmware Workstation is the following "10.0.1 build-1379776" to be true the Windows Server 2003 doesn't support the version 12 of it. I corrected my original message.

Comment: What is the version of the virtual hardware of your VM?

Comment: Sorry I don't get it virtual hardware, where I can gather this information. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMware workstation doesn't use the same format as ESXi for the Virtual Machines. They are similar, but the virtual hardware differs. That's why you can't just copy it over and start the VM.

Use the [VMware vCenter Conver](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter.html) to convert the VM to the ESXi format.

Comment: I have installed "VMware vCenter Converter Standalone Client" 6.1.1 build-3533064, when I try to convert, after selecting the .vmx file it think a bit and then I get the following answer "(X) The Virtual Disk is invalid or needs to be repaired" but the strange thing is that, the vm it runs without issues. Shoul I use the following comand:  vmware-vdiskmanager -R "D:\Virtual Machine\Windows 7\virtualdisk.vmdk"

Comment: Everything is fine I have repaired with the command above and then imported correctly, thank you very much indeed